# Is this the proper use of Objective-C protocols?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, protocols

I'm building an app with, for the purposes of this question, three custom classes: `AppDelegate`, `ListWindowController` and `ViewOptionsWindowController`. `AppDelegate` keeps retains properties of the single instances of `ListWindowController` and `ViewOptionsWindowController`.

When the user selects a particular menu item, an action in `AppDelegate` is executed that instantiates the `ViewOptionsWindowController`. Changes made in this controller's window need to be reflected in `ListWindowController`'s window (either adding or removing a column from the window's table view).

So, I've defined a protocol, `ViewOptionsChanged`, which has two required methods, `-addColumn` and `-removeColumn` (with parameters to indicate what to add or remove). I've indicated that `ListViewController` conforms to this protocol, and when instantiating `ViewOptionsWindowController` am passing `AppDelegate`'s instance of `ListViewController`. The declaration of `ViewOptionsWindowController`'s init method is:

```
- (id)initWithListController:(id <ViewOptionsChanged>)listController;
```

so that the only facts that `ViewOptionsWindowController` knows about the `listController` parameter is that it conforms to this protocol.

So, my question is, is this the proper use of Objective-C protocols? Or would some other design pattern be more appropriate?

Comment: Does 'ViewOptionsWindowController' need to remember when the settings change? If so, maybe having some settings object that notifies 'ListViewController' when settings have changed (whether they come from 'ViewOptionsWindowController' or not) is a more effective pattern?

Comment: Currently, in addition to toggling the view of columns based on the changes made in the ViewOptionsWindowController`'s window, the `ListViewController` is also writing the changes to the user defaults. Honestly, this doesn't seem quite right, it seems like this result of the changes should happen in the `AppDelegate`.

Comment: nono, don't move stuff to the app delegate, keep it separated. It is ok that it deals with user defaults IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes .. but I think it is a tad confusing. I'd make listView a proper delegate of viewOptions

maybe name the protocol ViewOptionsDelegate and the methods viewOptions:changedTo: and put the logic to add/remove columns in the listController?

feels more cocoa like and really logic about columns don't belong with viewOptions.

but ultimately -- even if you dont agree -- it is used ok IMO.

Comment: guess things depend on the specific project and taste as well -- to a certain degree!

Comment: I probably should have thought of calling it a delegate, as that does seem to be what it is. The term I originally used was `notifyee` in my source code. The only logic the `ViewOptionsWindowController` handles is whether or not checkboxes are checked, informing `ListViewController` of the change with `-addColumnWithIdentifier:` and `-removeColumnWithIdentifier:`.

Answer (score 1):

Delegation can be used for this, but, if this is a Mac app, consider [bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/WhatAreBindings.html) instead. Much less code, somewhat less entanglement, can be harder to debug. On either Mac or iOS, you could at least use [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html); simple to debug, somewhat less entanglement.

Comment: I'm going with the delegate idea for now, but will have to look into KVO.

Comment: Bindings are KVO+KVC .. nothing more nothing less. IF you decide to do this, I'd start out looking at KVO.